# While navigating HTML Elements with forEach, the getElementsByClassName function does not work on these elements

Tags: javascript, html

Let me try to explain, but you will understand better when you see the codes. I get my div elements with the `getElementsByClassName` function and then convert it to an array with the `Array.from()` function. While navigating this array with the forEach function, I am sending each element to a function. In this function, the item parameter represents my element. I can display this element with `console.log(item)` and even list its child elements with `item.children`. However, when I select this div with `document.getElementById()` using Inspect(F12) and then run the `getElementsByClassName` function only on this div, I do not get an error, but in the `item.getElementsByClassName` function I wrote in the html page, I get the error `'Uncaught TypeError: item.getELementsByClassName is not a function'`.

I leave the code I wrote below. Error in `registerClickOrdering` function.

```
function registerClickHandler() {
          $('.remove_question_div').click(function() {
            var removedId = parseInt($(this).parent().attr('id').split('-').slice(-1))
            $(this).parent().remove();
            
            var questions = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('questions')).slice(removedId-1)
            console.log(questions)
            questions.forEach((item, index) => {registerClickOrdering(item, index)})
          });
        }

const registerClickOrdering = (item, index) => {
      console.log(item)
      item.id=`question_div-${index+2}`
      var questionCounterLbl = item.getELementsByClassName('question-counter')[0]
      questionCounterLbl.textContent = `${index+1}. Soru`
      var questionTitle = item.getELementsByClassName('question-title')[0]
      questionTitle.name = `question-${index+1}`
      questionTitle.id = `id_question-${index+1}`
      var answerInputs = Array.from(item.getELementsByClassName('answers-input'))
      answerInputs.forEach((item) => {
        item.name = `answer-${index+1}`
      })

    }
```

Comment: You're using jQuery. Why are you bothering with `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: @Andy I don't know how to access elements inside just a selected element using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing everything right except for one, tiny thing that a linter could help you with in the future...

Change `getELementsByClassName` to `getElementsByClassName`

Happens to everyone at some point.

Comment: Thank you. I stood on this job so long that I never noticed that there was a capital letter L.

Comment: Ahhh the value of a second pair of eyes.   Definitely happens to all of us.